# Timer binding not working ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, ionic-framework

I have created a stopwatch factory service, doesn't really do much besides running (reset and other features not implemented, just ignore them).

I set a `$scope.time` to receive the changes of the timer, however it isn't being updated.

I have tried many different approaches the last one I guess is really bad practice but I wanted to try and make it work.

my view:

```
<ion-view view-title="Clock">
  <ion-content>
    <div ng-controller="controller as ClockCtrl">
      <h1 ng-bind="ClockCtrl.time"></h1>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

my Controller:

```
.controller('ClockCtrl', function($scope, Stopwatch) {
  var vm = $scope;
  $scope.time = "";
  Stopwatch.init($scope);
})
```

my service:

```
factory('Stopwatch', function() {
  var Stopwatch = (function() {
                var s;
                var isRunning = 0;
                var time = 0;
        var thatElement;
                function run(element){
                    if(isRunning !== 0){
                        time++;
                        s.mills = time % 10;
                        s.secs = Math.floor(time / 10);
                        s.mins = Math.floor(time / 10 / 60);
                        //Stopwatch.currentTime = ("0"+s.mins).slice(-2)+":"+("0"+s.secs).slice(-2)+":"+("0"+s.mills).slice(-2);
            thatElement.time = ("0"+s.mins).slice(-2)+":"+("0"+s.secs).slice(-2)+":"+("0"+s.mills).slice(-2);
                        setTimeout(run, 100);
                    }
                };

                return {
                    settings: {
                        currTime: "",
                        mills: 0,
                        secs: 0,
                        mins: 0,
                        i: 1,
                        times: ["00:00:00"],
                    },
                    currentTime: "",
                    init: function(element) {
                        thatElement = element;
                        s = this.settings;
                        this.start(element);
                    },
                    clear: function() {
                        s.i = 1,
                        s.mins = s.secs = s.mills = 0;
                        s.times = ["00:00:00"],
                        s.results.innerHTML = s.clearButton;
                    },
                    start:function(element){
                        isRunning = 1;
                        run(element);
                    },
                    stop: function(){
                        isRunning = 0;
                    }
                }

            })();
  return Stopwatch;
})
```

I know that the last approach is bad, I would accept any pointers, this is my first time using ionic, 2nd time trying angular.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use your customized filter for format of time. Here is a very good example explained with both $timeout and $interval. Plus with customized filter. Run the snippet and see how that work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285679/angularjs-how-to-make-a-stop-watch-starting-from-000000-format/32285912#32285912

Comment: Thanks for the nice reference, however in that example the code is inside of the controller and I want it to be fetched from the factory

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `controllerAs` syntax you need to set controller instance property, not `$scope` object one:

```
.controller('ClockCtrl', function($scope, Stopwatch) {
  this.time = "";
  Stopwatch.init(this);
});
```

Comment: Changing the code did not change the outcome unfortunately. any other ideas? when I debug I see that the vm.time is changing, but the binding doesn't (same as before).

Comment: You also need to pass `this` instead of `$scope` to `Stopwatch.init`.

Comment: Yea, I tried it as well when I saw your code. no luck :-\